# I am doing the classic recursion problem of counting stairs by taking one or two steps... but I have to output each combination

Tags: javascript, recursion, combinations

So the basic premise is given 'n' amount of stairs, find all possible combinations of taking either 1 or 2 steps at a time. Since I spent a lot of time learning how to solve the Fibonacci sequence with recursion, I instantly noticed the similarity between the two problems. I figured out how to solve for the number of combinations... but I am utterly stuck when trying to figure out how to output each possible combination.

Here is the solution I have come up with...

```js
function countWaysToReachNthStair(n) {
  if (n === 1) { return 1; }
  if (n === 2) { return 2; }
  
  return countWaysToReachNthStair(n-1) + countWaysToReachNthStair(n-2)
}

console.log(countWaysToReachNthStair(4));
```

Every time I try to add things to an array to the output I either get an error. Any tips or tricks would be much appreciated...

The expected outcome for calling

```
countWaysToReachNthStair(4)
```

would be

```
5 ((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2))
```

Comment: The expected combos to get 5 should also include [1,2,1]

Answer (score 3):

Generators are a great fit for problems dealing with combinations and permutations -

```js
function* ways(n) {
  if (n <= 0) return
  if (n <= 2) yield [n]
  for (const w of ways(n - 2)) yield [2, ...w]
  for (const w of ways(n - 1)) yield [1, ...w]
}

for (const w of ways(4))
  console.log(`(${w.join(",")})`)
```

```
(2,2)
(2,1,1)
(1,2,1)
(1,1,2)
(1,1,1,1)
```

If you are interested in the total count, you can gather all ways into an array and read the `length` property of the result -

```js
console.log(Array.from(ways(4)).length)
```

```
5
```

Comment: Hmm... I have never seen the word 'yield' used in JS before! Thanks for showing me I'll have to look into it!

Comment: note `yield` must be used within a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) function, `function* (...) { ... }`. i have [several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+generator) covering the topic. if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask :D

Answer (score 2):

More or less as the OP understands it...

```js
function waysToReachNthStair(n) {
  if (n === 1) return [[1]];         // there's one way to take 1 stair
  if (n === 2) return [[2], [1,1]];  // there are two ways to take 2 stairs
  
  return [
    // prepend 1 to each way we can take n-1 stairs, and
    // prepend 2 each way we can take n-2 stairs
    ...waysToReachNthStair(n-1).map(way => [1, ...way]),
    ...waysToReachNthStair(n-2).map(way => [2, ...way])
  ]
}

console.log(waysToReachNthStair(4));
```

Explaining map(), it says: given an array like `[x, y, z, ...]` and a function `f`, return a new array like `[f(x), f(y), f(z), ...]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really need to learn more about .map as I don't know much about it!

Comment: @DaShaman, sure thing. Edited for clarity and explaining map.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total number of steps and route to steps as:

```js
const result = [];

function countWaysToReachNthStairHelper(n, arr) {
  if (n === 1) {
    result.push(arr.join("") + "1");
    return 1;
  }
  if (n === 2) {
    const str = arr.join("");
    result.push(str + "1" + "1");
    result.push(str + "2");
    return 2;
  }
  arr.push(1);
  const first = countWaysToReachNthStairHelper(n - 1, arr);
  arr.pop();
  arr.push(2);
  const second = countWaysToReachNthStairHelper(n - 2, arr);
  arr.pop();

  return first + second;
}

function countWaysToReachNthStair(n) {
  return countWaysToReachNthStairHelper(n, []);
}

console.log(countWaysToReachNthStair(4));
console.log(result);
```